# Eclipse does not Display Swing Components Correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-editor

I am using Eclipse and Visual Editor (VE) for Eclipse:

- Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.2.20110218-0812
- Visual Editor 1.5.0.R20101202-1328

After several days of working on an GUI the VE WYSIWYG view does not display new components in the foreground. When I restart Eclipse the graphical components are shown as rectangles

When I "rollback" to a previous version of my files (incl. Eclipse workspace meta files) everything is Ok (after F5 synchronization) till it happens again. The application runs fine and all components are displayed correctly.

Does anybody experienced something similar?

Answer (score 1):

I second recommendation to stay away from VE. It is a project that seems to continuously have issues.

For a well regarded form designer, see Window Builder which was until recently a commercial product that made its creators (Instantiations) quite a bit of cash (see well regarded). Google has recently acquired Instantiations and contributed the editor to the open source community.

http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

Comment: Thank you very much for your input Konstantin. "sfrj" recommended another option: JFormdesigner (http://www.formdev.com/). I will experiment with both tools and decide.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with that visual editor too time ago. If you dont have to use an integrated tool i would highly recomend to avoid Visual Editor, and instead use JFormDesigner. Its not free, but you can have a look at the trial and if you like it maybe you could pay for it, download for free or whatever. I use it for my swings often, it is very intuitive and easy to use.

Link: http://www.formdev.com/

P.S
Also you can integrate this tool with eclipse.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input "sfri". Konstantin recommended another option: Windowbuilder (http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/). I will experiment with both tools and decide.